# Access to selected resources via OAuth

Tags: oauth, permissions

is it possible (and does it make sense) to use OAuth for granting permissions to selected resources? Any example and Use Case I found so far cares about the question how to grant access to whole permission areas ("access user profile data", "access object data"). What I need is to "Grant read access to object XY". Is OAuth capable to do this? If not, are there any alternatives?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

this really depends on the service provider specs. when you say "object XY", if you mean a specific json object then the answer is yes. many service providers return json or xml data. oauth can return at most:

- data that the service provider permits, and
- data that you (the app) has requested, and
- data that the user allows you to retrieve

all of these conditions must be met before your app gets any data from the service provider. but if the service provider has the object you require in its oauth scope (in oauth2 lingo) then you can get it.

i may have misunderstood your question though. which service provider(s) are you interested in, or are you considering setting up a service provider of your own?

Comment: I will implement both a client and an OAuth Provider.

Comment: in that case you can make as many oauth endpoints you like and you can store whatever you want on each endpoint. you can basically think of these endpoints as json files, accessible over the net, which require a password before users can access them